# Linux script or program to shorten filenames

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, rename

I haven't had much success in finding a Linux version of [namemangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/), which I need to rename 1000 of files so they are readable on Windows.

Does anyone know of a Linux program that can do this?

If not, then a script might work as I only need to rename all files in a folder to, say, the first 16 characters. I suspect that the script route might be worth going down but not sure where to start.

Comment: You probably could write quickly a Python or Perl or Ocaml or Ruby script doing that.

Comment: Why can't you just use a vfat filesystem, which allows long file names?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long are does names and what do they contain that they are not recognised by Windows?

Answer (score 12):

On Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, if you enter `man rename` at a command prompt, you'll get the manual page for a rename utility that allows arbitrary Perl-like regular expression commands to be used in the renaming.

For example, this will shorten (by truncating) all files in the current directory to a length of five:

```
rename 's/^(.{5}).*/$1/' *
```

It works by capturing the first five characters then using that in the substitution, removing the rest.

Another example is to shorten filenames (sans extension) to five characters wile *preserving* the extension:

```
rename 's/^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/' *
```

It captures *two* groups, the first being the first five character, the second being the extension. This would turn `myCarefullyCraftedDocument.pdf` into `myCar.pdf`.

**Warning:** Use this *carefully,* preferably on a *copy* of your directory, or by taking backups first. You have been warned!! At a bare minimum, use `rename -n` first, which will show you what would be done without actually doing it.

Comment: will this get rid of the prefix as in PDF? and what would happen to files with the same name once shorten?

Comment: That particular example will, yes. You can write a regex to leave the extension alone. I'll update the answer. It also protects against overwriting files that already exist, so later renames will fail.

Comment: thanks for your help on this - I'm very thankful. I do have one slight issue if some of the pdfs will be renamed to 5 lets say what would happen to the PDF's it tries to rename with the same name? Is they a way we can just add a unique number onto all the ones with this is? see below ename -n 's/^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/' *
Annexes 123114345234525.pdf renamed as Annex.pdf
Annexes 123114432452352.pdf renamed as Annex.pdf

Comment: @Grimlockz, I don't _think_ you can put that sort of intelligence into the rename regex itself. What you may need to do is write a script to wrap rename with that sort of intelligence, and that's better asked as a separate question so you'll get more people responding than just I.

Comment: @Grimlockz This is why you don't want to do *everything* in a regex. You'll be happier and better off writing a script that uses regexes.

Comment: Should this still work on Ubuntu 18.04? I have `rename.ul` instead of `rename`. I get the `rename` man page when I run `man which.ul`, but `rename.ul -n 's/^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/' *` gives me no output in any directory I try.

Comment: `-n` can help similar to `powershell whatif flag`.

Answer (score 3):

You can move conflicted files to other directory:

```
for i in *
do
    j=${i:0:16}

    if [ -e "$j" ]
    then
        mv "$i" /path/to/rename/later
    else
        mv "$i" "$j"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell/python/perl scripting for this kind of thing is just fine, but it seems like a gui app would be best for you, so I would recommend [pyRenamer](http://www.infinicode.org/code/pyrenamer/), which can do exactly what you want, among many other things (simple common operations via presets [getting rid of spaces, truncating filename from one point to another], simple search/replace, complicated regex, previewer, etc).

Your distribution might even have it in their software repository (Fedora does).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script to shorten file names and remove characters that Windows doesn't like in a few lines of bash. Warning, untested code, typed directly into my browser.

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob
for x in *; do
  y=${x//+([!-!#$%&'().0-9@A-Z^_`a-z{}~])/_}  # change all problematic characters to _
  if [[ $y = .* ]]; then y=_${y#.}; fi        # change dot files to begin with _
  y=${y:0:16}                                 # truncate names
  y=${y,,}                                    # convert to lowercase
  if [[ -e $y || $y =~ ^(aux|clock\$|com[0-9]|con|lpt[0-9]|nul|prn)(\.*)?$ ]]; then
    # The file exists or is a DOS/Windows reserved name.
    # Change foo.bar to foo~1.bar, foo~2.bar, ... (I ignore the length restriction here)
    i=1
    if [[ $y =~ \. ]]; then
      prefix=${y%%.*}; suffix=.${y#*.}
    else
      prefix=$y; suffix=
    fi
    y=${prefix}~$i$suffix
    while [[ -e $y ]]; do
      ((++i))
      y=${prefix}~$i$suffix
    done
  fi
  mv -- "$x" "$y"
done
```

If you need to recurse into subdirectories, call a shell script from `find -depth -exec …`. Or use zsh instead of bash; in zsh, `**/*(od)` expands to all the files under the current directory, recursively, with more deeply nested files first.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems do not have the `rename` command, so as an alternative to paxdiablo's answer, here is how to do the same thing with `mv`.

```
for f in *.pdf; do 
    tmp=`echo $f | sed -r 's//^(.{5}).*(\..*)$/$1$2/'`
    mv -b ./"$f" ./"$tmp"
done
```

The `-b` flag on move creates a backup of files that would be deleted or overwritten. By changing the glob pattern in the for loop you can adjust what files it runs on, using `*` by itself to run on all files.

Comment: No need to use `echo` and a pipe (could be very expensive if you have a lot of files), use a heredoc or herestring instead.

Comment: @ChrisDown Oh? I thought that heredocs created a temp file and then redirected stdin of the program. A pipe is just a redirect, so that's a wash, and it now has to spend time creating a temp file. Where did you hear this?

Comment: Heredocs don't create a temp file. That would be unnecessary. A pipe is not a redirect, it creates a subshell, which is expensive.

Comment: @ChrisDown [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7252771/724357). [According to the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), the piped processes are forked, but it says nothing about running them in their own shells.

Comment: It forks a subshell. It even says it in the article you just linked...

Comment: @ChrisDown for the pipemill, yes. running `cat - | tail -20` in a shell, then running `ps` from a separate shell shows cat and tail as child processes, but does not show extra bash processes. I find this confusing, if they are subshelled.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept, so this discussion isn't very productive. Either way this is clearly documented in `man bash` under `Pipelines`. ("Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).")

Comment: For example, notice the difference between `eval 'echo $BASH_SUBSHELL'` and `eval 'echo $BASH_SUBSHELL' | cat`.

Comment: @ChrisDown ok, so what I've called child processes is also synonymous with subshell. Huh. I always thought a subshell was another instance of the *shell* itself.

Comment: I just did a quick test, `time`ing a loop using `echo $i | sed` and another using `sed ... <<<$i`, and the herestring took about 2/3 the time of the echo.

Comment: @Kevin I note you used `<<<` instead of `<<`. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: @SpencerRathbun Yes. `<<` starts a here<i>doc</i>, which is multi-line and requires delimiters. `<<<` creates a here<i>string</i>, which just takes one variable/string. Try it out, `var=abc // cat<<<$var // cat <<$var`.

Comment: @Kevin So do heredoc's use temp files as indicated [here](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-here.html) and a few other places? Running a quick test between a herestring and heredoc with `time`, I got a slightly slower time for the heredoc. Which makes sense if it dumps the contents into a temp file.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun I don't see it explicitly mentioned, but I'd imagine it goes through a private fifo.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to experiment with renaming files and happen to have KDE libraries installed on your system (or don't mind adding them), check out krename.

It allows you to do quite a few simple renaming tasks directly with its tools and also allows regular expressions for more complicated situations.

It shows you a preview of the renamed files as you build the renaming conditions.  It also allows you to rename the same files again which is helpful if you want to do something complicated where doing it in stages would reduce the complexity of each stage to something you can figure out quickly.

Answer (score -1):

```
for file in *; do
    mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
done &
```