# Shorten Linux Filename (truncate on a symbol)

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have a list of files in Linux that I want to shorten. They are in the following format: WhatIWant_WhatIDoNotWant.txt.

Is there an easy way to make them: WhatIWant.txt? I saw the following question (link below) and I really like the for do loop (just in case the result has a duplicate), but I don't know how to get the place value of the underscore (_) to feed that in instead of using the 16th character as the ending point...

[Linux script or program to shorten filenames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33060/linux-script-or-program-to-shorten-filenames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# We loop over the files with filename suffix .txt

for f in *.txt; do
    # We rename the file removing _ and the remaining part including the extension
    mv -- "$f" "${f/_*}.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

The variable expansion `${varname%_*}` will strip off everything from the (last) `_` to the end of the string.

So, for example

```
$ name=WhatIWant_WhatIDontWant.txt
$ echo "${name%_*}"
WhatIWant
```

Note it also removes the `.txt`.

So we can build a simple loop:

```
for name in *.txt
do
  mv -i -- "$name" "${name%_*}.txt"
done
```

If you want this recursive then something like

```
find . -name '*.txt' | while read -r "name"
do
  mv -i "$name" "${name%_*}.txt"
done
```

might be sufficient, but beware if any file has an embedded return character; that'd break this loop.